# Opening PDF in New Window and go to Specific page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, iframe, pdf-generation

Open PDF in new window or in IFrame and goto Specific Page.
Am using a href to open in a new window. However, am able to open the pdf in a new window in both the desktop browser and in mobile app browser.
However, I wasn't able to go to a specific page.

Spring MVC and HTML5 Vue component

```
Eg: <a href="http://www.example.com/viewdocument" target="_blank">view document</a>
```

I tried with the iframe as well. By using iframe am able to load in desktop browsers. However, failing to load the pdf in mobile browsers.

Am working on an HTML5 App.

```
<iframe id="legal-iframe" src="http://www.example.com/viewdocument/" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Backend am using Spring MVC and using the below headers

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename='test.pdf#page=2'");
headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

Am looking for either javascript solution or using any pdf library to go to a specific page and flush the byte array. The browser renders and opens a specific page

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<embed/>` tag with the `page` attribute:

```
<embed src="http://www.example.com/viewdocument" 
       type="application/pdf" 
       width="100%" 
       height="600px" 
       page="5"/>
```

See futher:

https://www.codexworld.com/embed-pdf-document-file-in-html-web-page/

Comment: Thanks Alan! It is not working in Mobile Browsers.  We tried leveraging https://pdfobject.com/static/. But no luck worked!